# Missing word in "une dizaine de mesures ___"

Tags: demande-de-mot

While listening to news about Emmanuel Macron, I heard this sentence

> Il devrait s'articuler autour d'une dizaine de mesures ___. Les Français pourront alors juger.

The missing word sounds like "far", but I looked up the dictionary and apparently *far* means "prune custard flan", so it's probably not the word I'm looking for. I guess one could say *une dizaine de mesures clé*, but this is not what was said in the news.

Comment: Can you give a link so that we can listen to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably:

> Il devrait s'articuler autour d'une dizaine de mesures *phare(s)*. Les Français pourront alors juger.

A *phare* is a lighthouse. But in this context, a *mesure phare* is like a central point of his campaign, something important, that will guide his action, be very recognizable... whereas other measures won't necessarily be *phare* but more mundane.

I do not know if *phare* should be plural or not in this case.

Comment: Why should it *not* be in the plural?

Comment: Nouns used as adjectives do not necessarily take the plural. Consider e.g. _des chaussures marron_.

Comment: @AlexandreFlak [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/phare#Adjectif) has the plural form, and in fact even this particular example *des mesures phares*.

Comment: Yes, and so does this reference from [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4830). But I don't know where that usage comes from.

Comment: I'll stay neutral on that plural: I don't know for sure. It's a case for La Dictée de Benard Pivot :-)

Answer (score 2):

mesure phares - a bit like "showcase measures"

Comment: Yes, that's it - although both "mesure" and "phare" should be in the plural. See e.g. [here](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4830).

Comment: Maybe you could explain the relevance of *phare* in this context. I don't agree with @AlexandreFlak about the plural on both words but actually you could reflect the formula in the original question *mesures phare*, on a par with *mesures clé*.